# 2D Spatial partitioning alternatives to spatial hashes and quadtrees

Tags: c#, collision-detection, physics, tree

I've been trying to implement a spatial partitioning algorithm in my game, but both spatial hashes and quadtrees aren't what I'm looking for.

My level size is not supposed to have a limit (only Int32 limits). I need a spatial partitioning algorithm that doesn't need a "Level Width" and a "Level Height".

I have many moving physical objects. I need the algorithm to be fast enough to support 500+ objects.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with fixed 2D grids.

I've made two videos which explain in-depth how I implemented them, and the current implementation is available on my GitHub page: https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HY_SqqaoL4

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYB37BDtHuQ

Answer (score 14):

#### Dynamic Tree

[Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/) is a well optimized engine designed by an [experienced physics/game programmer](https://plus.google.com/114825651948330685771/about).  Originally Box2D used a hash grid that required a fixed height and width.

When Erin upgraded to a better broadphase algorithm he went with Nathanael Presson's btDbvt.  This is the broadphase used by Bullet Physics.  Erin modified and optimized the algorithm for 2d.

You can read a super high level overiew in the [Box2D manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) ( §4.11, or search for Dynamic Tree).

Here's an except from the in [code documentation](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/b2DynamicTree.h#53) (which is very good considering it's not part of the public API).

> A dynamic AABB tree broad-phase, inspired by Nathanael Presson's
> btDbvt.  A dynamic tree arranges data in a binary tree to accelerate
> queries such as volume queries and ray casts. Leafs are proxies  with
> an AABB. In the tree we expand the proxy AABB by b2_fatAABBFactor  so
> that the proxy AABB is bigger than the client object. This allows the
> client object to move by small amounts without triggering a tree
> update.
>
> Nodes are pooled and relocatable, so we use node indices rather than
> pointers.

My understanding of the Dynamic Tree's algorithm is this.  The Dynamic tree is the cross between a classic [avl binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and a quadtree.  The end effect is a quadtree that that only splits each node in half, and the split line isn't fixed (the two halves aren't equal sized like a quad tree).  AVL comes in because quadree with dynamic splits can degenerate to essentially a list (O(n) lookup speed).  The AVL is used to rebalance subtrees so to ensure O lg(N) lookup speed.

Best of all the code is MIT so feel free to copy / derived / shamelessly-steal / etc.

Comment: Looks... complex! I will take a look at it, though. Someone suggested me using the "sweep and prune" or "sort and sweep" technique but I couldn't find anything about a C# or .NET implementation. I found a c++ example but it's confusing and it didn't work (I tried to implement it anyway). Do you think SAP would be easier to implement? Is there are .NET implementation?

Answer (score 8):

This is very close to a [similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13349/7881) asked here on Gamedev, but seeing as you're concerned with performance and not file storage, perhaps [my answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/a-way-to-store-potentially-infinite-2d-map-data/13388#13388) there will be of more use to you. I'll include the bulk of it here for completeness, but the original answer provides a little more depth if you want to look into it.

> I ran into a similar problem and decided to create my own structure to
>   handle the data. It's based loosely on a quadtree, but has infinite
>   (at least as big as an Int) expandability in all directions. It was
>   designed to handle grid-based data which expanded from a central
>   point, much like Minecraft does now. It is space efficient in memory,
>   and very fast.
>
> My code can be found [here](http://j.mp/mtRWVq). The code is complete, tested (unit-
>   and load-tests), and quite optimized. The inner workings aren't too
>   well documented yet, however, but all the public methods are so it
>   should be usable. If anyone decides to try it out, feel free to
>   contact me with questions or comments.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a relatively small number ( < several thousand) of smallish objects (most objects aren't big enough to potentially collide with a lot other objects) I find that a simple x-ordered list of axially aligned bounding boxes (AABBs) works pretty well. I just put the objects in a list, then each frame after moving the objects, I quick sort the list by x value, then make one pass through the list checking for AABB proximity. For each object, I check it against the objects ahead of it in the list until I either reach the end of the list or an object which is out of x range; that is, it's left edge's x value is > x value of the right edge of the object being tested. It basically dynamically divides space into sometimes-overlapping, AABB-x-width-sized slices. It's pretty easy to understand and implement and it works pretty well for the targeted sub set of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [r-tree algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is what you are looking for.

I works really well for static geometry, but you can also use it for moving objects by removing and adding objects at their new positions.

Comment: I tried a C# implementation, and the performance was way too bad when "removing and adding objects at their new position".